# Add the product ID after the cart item name in WooCommerce cart page for specific products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm looking to hook into the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter in WooCommerce and would like to display the product ID after the name ONLY for a specific Product.

I'm looking at this code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'just_a_test', 10, 3 );
function just_a_test( $item_name,  $cart_item,  $cart_item_key ) {
    // Display name and product id here instead
    echo $item_name.' ('.$cart_item['product_id'].')';
}
```

This indeed returns the name with a product ID but it applies on all Products on my store.

Only want to display the product ID for a specified product. I'm curious how I'd go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have the product ID of that product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, given by jpneey does not work (HTTP ERROR 500) because:

- `echo` was used instead of `return`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // The targeted product ids, multiple product IDs can be entered, separated by a comma
    $targeted_ids = array( 30, 815 );
    
    // Product ID
    $product_id = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];
    
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $targeted_ids ) ) {
        return $item_name . ' (' . $product_id . ')';
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You can do this by applying some **basic conditioning**.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'just_a_test', 10, 3 );
function just_a_test( $item_name,  $cart_item,  $cart_item_key ) {
    $product_ids = array(68, 421);
    if(in_array($cart_item['product_id'], $product_ids) {
        echo $item_name.' ('.$cart_item['product_id'].')';
    } else {
        echo $item_name;
    }
}
```

Note that I've used an `array` of product ids incase that your problem may need this function to apply on two or more product ids. Alternatively, you can just use this:

```
//single product id
$product_id = 68;
echo $item_name . ($cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id) ? ' ('.$cart_item['product_id'].')' : '';
```